# Getting the following when trying to run a rake import on spree 1.0.1 rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, rake, spree

Trying to import data with a rake task and i get the following:

```
[DEPRECATION] `insert_after` hook method is deprecated, replace hook call with: 
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "layouts/admin",
                 :name => "converted_admin_tabs_544163069",
                 :insert_after => "[data-hook='admin_tabs'], #admin_tabs[data-hook]",
                 :text => "<%= tab(:product_imports) %>",
                 :disabled => false)

[WARNING] Deface railtie has not initialized yet, override 'converted_admin_tabs_112463983' is being declared too early.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- delayed/backend/active_record
```

Answer (score 1):

```
no such file to load -- delayed/backend/active_record
```

This error is coming from Delayed Job. Based on this discussion  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/delayed_job/GdxiB6RVAp0 it appears specifying:

```
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
```

in an initializer might solve this problem.

```
[DEPRECATION] `insert_after` hook method is deprecated, replace hook call with:
```

This warning is a symptom of the new version of rails. Simply removing the insert_after and adding the code it suggests should make it go away.